# LINQ/PLINQ AsNoTracking / AsParallel Performance - Usage

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, plinq

I've read that if you only need to read entities (not to update them) it is better to use AsNoTracking().

As for AsParallel() some dude said it's always better to measure (e.g. Stopwatch) and to decide whether to use it or not.

Now I am going through my code to decide where to use these for a better performance.

my question is... am I getting too far? I ended up using them almost everywhere, even on simple stuff like:

```
ctx.SomeTable.AsNoTracking().AsParallel().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3)
```

or

```
(from x in ctx.SomeTable select 
    new SomeClass ()
        {
         // .....
}).AsNoTracking().Take(() => 20).AsParallel().ToList()
```

Am I going too far?
What are the best practices regarding AsNoTracking / AsParallel?

Comment: Have you ended up using `AsParallel` almost everywhere after having convinced yourself -through measurements conducted with a `Stopwatch`- that it is beneficial for performance?

Comment: Not yet =) I didn't yet measured / used AsParallel() - Only put it in a few places and noticed it doesn't crash, it still works. But I've put AsNoTracking everywhere where I'm only reading stuff (not updating). I feel like I'm abusing it.

Comment: Remove `AsParallel` if you don't know for which purpose it is introduced, In your case it will just slowdown execution. `AsNoTracking` only needed if you do not  use custom projection - `Select`

Comment: AsParallel() is only useful if you are running intensive calculations on your query. If you are doing simple operations, it is much faster to run the calculations serially.

Its easier to think of it this way, Parallization is useful if your calculations are blocking. For example calculating prime numbers, these calculations take a long time alone, we can speed things up by processing multiple at once. However, something like what you are doing, the processing is so quick, it would take more time to run it on separate threads and wait for all the changes to be merged at the end.

Comment: If you are not going to be re-storing the changes to your database using EF, AsNoTracking() is ideal as it doesn't have to maintain an execution plan for saving the changes you are making on database objects back to your database.

Comment: Here you can find some good materials to build solid understanding for AsParallel: [1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en), [2](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/ParallelProgramsinNET4_CodingGuidelines.pdf), [3](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/WhenToUseParallelForEachOrPLINQ.pdf)

Comment: `AsParallel().ToList()` will not give any benefits, since `AsParallel` only impacts code _after it_. And `ToList` is, by nature synchronous.